Медиа запросы работают не корректно
У меня не корректно работают медиа запросы.
Возможно проблема в библиотеке Bootstrap(версия 4.6).
На первой картинке работает нормально.

На второй, несмотря на медиа запрос "@madia (max-width: 991px)" и ширину экрана 991px,
применяется свойства от медиа запроса "@madia (max-width: 1200px)".

Подскажите пожалуйста как это исправит?
